# Using get_posts WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to use `get_posts()` to retrieve posts that have certain topics attached to them, in my custom post type named 'leaders'

Here is my query.

```
$args = array(
    'post-type' => 'leaders',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
     'key' => 'topics',
     'value' => '1773',
     'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)
);
```

`$test = get_posts( $args );`
If I `var_dump` the posts meta data i get this

```
topics  a:4:{i:0;s:4:"1773";i:1;s:4:"1783";i:2;s:4:"1763";i:3;s:4:"1753";}
```

However my `get_posts` just returns null, can anyone see why?

Comment: post_type instead of post-type perhaps?

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thank you!

Comment: It happens to everyone, no problem!